# Why is this code outputting the wrong answer?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, probability, equation

I'm new to both StackOverflow and coding so I appreciate any and all support!

I'm trying to solve for x in this equation: `x = (p^4).((15-(4p))-((10(p^2))/(1-((2p).(1-p)))))`

I wrote the below Python code in PyCharm in order to calculate 'x'.
When `p=60`, the output I expect is `0.735729231` but the output I get when I run the code is `[-2981888998.72899]`

I'd appreciate some guidance on what I'd need to change in order to output the expected value.

Many thanks!

PS: [for reference: here is an image showing the equation written in its original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4qRy.png)

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

p = 60
x = symbols('x')

eqn = Eq(x,(p**4)*((15-(4*p))-((10*(p**2))/(1-((2*p)*(1-p))))))
sol = solve(eqn,x)

print(sol)
```

Comment: Why do you need sympy here at all? This is just an arithmetic calculation of the right side for a given "p".

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm new to coding and have been following tutorials. I assumed I may have needed it to do maths calculations Thanks for the response.

Comment: Note that you can leave out quite some brackets. Due to precedence rules. `print(p**4*(15 - 4*p - (10*p**2 / (1 - 2*p*(1-p)))))` is the same expression.  You can use sympy here to simplify the expression `from sympy.abc import p; print(((p**4)*((15-(4*p))-((10*(p**2))/(1-((2*p)*(1-p)))))).factor())` gives `p**4*(3 - 2*p)*(4*p**2 - 8*p + 5)/(2*p**2 - 2*p + 1)`

Comment: @JohanC Yes good point. I tend to include more brackets than necessary more so to ensure I've grouped the parts of the equation correctly but I can certainly see how your suggestion cleans up the code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there something wrong with your calculation or your equation.

You can do this directly without any packages,

```
p = 60
print((p**4)*((15-(4*p))-((10*(p**2))/(1-((2*p)*(1-p))))))
```

You don't need sympy to solve this because all the p variables are on the right side already. x is basically just your answer for subbing in p = 60 and expanding and solving the equation.

And You get the same number `-2981888998.72899`

Comment: I appreciating you letting me know I didn't need any packages to solve this type of equation. (I'm new to coding). I've edited my post to include an image of the equation in it's original format. You said you think my equation may be wrong - could you let me know if the code I entered in Python does not correspond with the equation in the image?

Comment: it looks exactly the same to me, you need to double check your equation

Comment: @Mikey i just saw your equation in the image, i think you created it wrongly, give me a minute to convert it and check

Comment: You're correct, my calculation is wrong and I've just realised my classic error. I set p=60 instead of p=0.6. It now works as expected! Thank you so much for the speedy response!

Comment: ah okay. haha its always something stupid like that.